# investing in three stocks with minimum investment

Tags: combinatorics

An investor wishes to invest up to ¤12K in three different stocks. Each investment
must be made in units of ¤1K. How many different possible investment strategies
does he have?

Comment: So, you are asking how many ways the sum of three nonnegative integers, $x+y+z \le 12$?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Write them out.

0 0 12

0 1 11

0 2 10

0 3 9

0 4 8

0 5 7

0 6 6

1 1 10

1 2 9

1 3 8

1 4 7

1 5 6

2 2 8

2 3 7

2 4 6

2 5 5

3 3 6

3 4 5

4 4 4

Now for each combination take the # of permutations and then add all those numbers up.

For example, for 0 0 12, we have $\frac{3!}{2!}$, 3! because there are 3 elements and 2! because there are 2 elements that are the same.

Same for 1 1 10: $\frac{3!}{2!}$

What about 1 2 9?

What about 4 4 4?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  This will get to the answer, but can you think of an approach that doesn't require a "write them out" step?

Comment: @hardmath Dynamic programming?

Comment: Since the OP wants only a count ("how many different..."), I was thinking about the usual stars-and-bars treatment, discussed in many previous Questions.